# Google Cloud Identity Platform SAML authentication request signing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

Does Cloud Identity sign SAML authentication requests, and if yes, where can I get the signing key that it uses.

Answer (score 0):

No, Cloud Identity Platform initiate a SAML flow and validate the received assertion. Cloud Identity doesn't act as SAML IdP.

You have to provide the certificate of your IdP for allowing Cloud Identity Platform to validate the IdP signature.

Comment: Why would it need to act as IdP for this? The SP can sign the SAML request before sending it to the IdP, and the IdP can check the signature using a key that was provided to it. For example Auth0 documentation states that they will sign the SAML requests and allow you to download the key they use. They even let you provide your own key https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-configuration/special-configuration-scenarios/signing-and-encrypting-saml-requests#sign-the-saml-authentication-request